Sequelize Alias mismatch
## Product Model ##
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    unit_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'units',
        key: 'id'
      },
    },
    moving_category_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'moving_category',
        key: 'id'
      },
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'products',
    timestamps: true,
  });

  Product.associate = (models) => {
    Product.belongsTo(models.Unit, { foreignKey: 'unit_id' });
    Product.belongsTo(models.MovingCategory, { foreignKey: 'moving_category_id' });
    Product.belongsToMany(models.Purchase, {
      through: models.PurchaseProducts,
      foreignKey: 'product_id',
      otherKey: 'purchase_id',
      as: 'Purchases' // Optional alias
    });
    Product.belongsToMany(models.FactoryIssue, {
      through: models.ProductIssue,
      foreignKey: 'product_id',
      otherKey: 'product_issue_id',
      as: 'FactoryIssue' // Optional alias
    });


  };

  return Product;
};

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const FactoryIssue = sequelize.define(
    'FactoryIssue',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      machine_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'factory_machine',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      },
      issue_date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      issued_by: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      },
      issued_to: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      warehouse_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'warehouse',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
      tableName: 'factory_issue',
      indexes: [
        { fields: ['machine_id'] },
        { fields: ['issue_date'] },
        { fields: ['issued_by'] },
        { fields: ['warehouse_id'] }
      ]
    }
  );

## Factory Issue Model ##

  FactoryIssue.associate = (models) => {
    FactoryIssue.belongsTo(models.FactoryMachine, {
      foreignKey: 'machine_id',
      as: 'Machine',
    });
    FactoryIssue.belongsTo(models.Warehouse, {
      foreignKey: 'warehouse_id',
      as: 'Warehouse',
    });
    FactoryIssue.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'issued_by',
      as: 'IssuedBy',
    });
    // Updated association with ProductIssue
    FactoryIssue.hasMany(models.ProductIssue, {
      foreignKey: 'issue_id',
      as: 'ProductIssues', // Ensure this alias matches
    });
    // Updated many-to-many relationship through ProductIssue
    FactoryIssue.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
      through: models.ProductIssue,
      foreignKey: 'issue_id',
      otherKey: 'product_id',
      as: 'Products', // Ensure this is consistent with your requirement
    });
    FactoryIssue.belongsToMany(models.Stock, {
      through: models.IssueStock,
      foreignKey: 'issue_id',
      otherKey: 'stock_id',
      as: 'Stocks',
    });
  };
  
  return FactoryIssue;
};

## ProductIssue Model ##
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ProductIssue = sequelize.define('ProductIssue', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    issue_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'factory_issue',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    },
    product_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'products',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    },
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    warehouse_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'warehouse',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    tableName: 'product_issue',
    indexes: [
      { fields: ['issue_id'] },
      { fields: ['product_id'] },
      { fields: ['warehouse_id'] }
    ]
  });

  ProductIssue.associate = (models) => {
    ProductIssue.belongsTo(models.FactoryIssue, { 
      foreignKey: 'issue_id',
      as: 'FactoryIssue'
    });
    ProductIssue.belongsTo(models.Product, { 
      foreignKey: 'product_id',
      as: 'Product'
    });
    ProductIssue.belongsTo(models.Warehouse, {
      foreignKey: 'warehouse_id',
      as: 'Warehouse',
    });
  };

  return ProductIssue;
};
 
## Controller to create a factory Issue ##
const createFactoryIssue = async (req, res) => {
  const transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();

  try {
    const {
      issue_date,
      machine_id,
      issued_by,
      issued_to,
      warehouse_id, // Single warehouse ID for the FactoryIssue
      items,        // Array of items [{ product_id, quantity }]
    } = req.body;

    // Check required fields for the factory issue
    if (!issue_date || !machine_id || !issued_by || !issued_to || !warehouse_id || !items || !items.length) {
      return errorResponse(res, 'All required fields, including items, must be filled.', null, 400);
    }

    // Check if all referenced entities exist
    const [machine, user, warehouse] = await Promise.all([
      FactoryMachine.findByPk(machine_id),
      User.findByPk(issued_by),
      Warehouse.findByPk(warehouse_id),
    ]);

    if (!machine) return errorResponse(res, 'Machine not found', null, 404);
    if (!user) return errorResponse(res, 'User not found', null, 404);
    if (!warehouse) return errorResponse(res, 'Warehouse not found', null, 404);

    // Validate all products in the items array
    const productIds = items.map(item => item.product_id);
    const products = await Product.findAll({
      where: { id: productIds },
    });

    if (products.length !== items.length) {
      const missingIds = productIds.filter(id => !products.some(product => product.id === id));
      return errorResponse(res, `Products with IDs ${missingIds.join(', ')} not found`, null, 404);
    }

    // Create the new FactoryIssue
    const newFactoryIssue = await FactoryIssue.create(
      {
        issue_date,
        machine_id,
        issued_by,
        issued_to,
        warehouse_id, // Associate the warehouse with the FactoryIssue
      },
      { transaction }
    );

    // Check and update stock for each product in the specified warehouse
    for (const item of items) {
      const { product_id, quantity } = item;

      // Fetch stock for the product at the specified warehouse
      const stock = await Stock.findOne({
        where: { product_id, warehouse_id },
        transaction,
      });

      if (!stock || stock.quantity < quantity) {
        await transaction.rollback();
        return errorResponse(
          res,
          `Insufficient stock for product ID ${product_id} at warehouse ${warehouse_id}. Available: ${stock ? stock.quantity : 0}`,
          null,
          400
        );
      }

      // Subtract the quantity from the stock
      stock.quantity -= quantity;
      await stock.save({ transaction });

      // Insert a record into ProductIssue
      await ProductIssue.create(
        {
          issue_id: newFactoryIssue.id,
          product_id,
          quantity,
          warehouse_id,
        },
        { transaction }
      );

      // Insert a record into IssueStock
      await IssueStock.create(
        {
          issue_id: newFactoryIssue.id,
          product_id,
          quantity,
          warehouse_id,
          issued_by,
          issue_date,
        },
        { transaction }
      );
    }

    // Commit the transaction
    await transaction.commit();

    // Fetch the complete FactoryIssue with associated ProductIssue records for the response
    const completeFactoryIssue = await FactoryIssue.findByPk(newFactoryIssue.id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: ProductIssue,
          as: 'Products', // Changed from 'ProductIssue' to 'ProductIssues'
          include: [{ model: Product }],
        },
      ],
    });

    return successResponse(res, 'Factory issue created successfully', completeFactoryIssue, 201);
  } catch (error) {
    // Rollback the transaction if it's still active
    if (!transaction.finished) {
      await transaction.rollback();
    }
    console.error('Error creating factory issue:', error);
    return errorResponse(res, 'Server error', error.message, 500);
  }
};

Getting an error while creating a factoryIssue using the factoryIssueController.
The error: ProductIssue is associated to FactoryIssue using an alias. You've included an alias (Products), but it does not match the alias(es) defined in your association (ProductIssues).

You should use exactly those aliases you indicated in associations:
// using has-many + belongs-to
const completeFactoryIssue = await FactoryIssue.findByPk(newFactoryIssue.id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: ProductIssue,
          as: 'ProductIssues', // has-many alias
          include: [{
            model: Product,
            as: 'Product' // belongs-to alias
          }],
        },
      ],
    });

// using belongs-to-many
const completeFactoryIssue = await FactoryIssue.findByPk(newFactoryIssue.id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: Product,
          as: 'Products' // belongs-to-many alias
        },
      ],
    });

